# Zero Copy bytes in grpc c++

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I just started to use gRPC, and I noticed that bytes in C++ compiled into `std::string`, which means that every gRPC object that arrives at the service needs to be copied to a new buffer because of `std::string` ownership.

I don't want to copy every object to new buffer before using it (too many allocations).

Is there any known solution, or am I using gRPC wrong?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC just uses protobufs. You can move stuff out of protobuf `Message` by calling the generated `release_XXX()` methods.

> `string* release_foo()`: Releases the ownership of the field and returns the pointer of the `string` object. After calling this, caller takes the ownership of the allocated `string` object and `foo()` will return the empty string/empty bytes.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated

Comment: I need to release the binary data from the std::string not from the protobuf generated object.

Comment: There's no way to release the binary data from `std::string`. If you want to use gRPC without any copies you will need to organize your storage to use `std::string` internally.